# How to setup QoS on router (prioritize VOIP and web browsing over downloading)?

Tags: linux, download, qos, voip

I've got Asus WL500GP-v2 router with renewed Oleg's firmware installed (http://code.google.com/p/wl500g/ , the stable version).

I would like to setup some Quality of Service to ensure all users are able to browse web or use VOIP when one of them is mass downloading (torrent or http) or streaming online video or playing some online game.

I also would like to prioritize local traffic from a NAS server that is in the same LAN and has a static IP address over VOIP communication (there is a backup service on NAS installed).

I found that the router has WonderShaper installed (wshaper). How can I use this to achieve the policy?

Or should I use something else? I have found a Prometheus QoS (http://gpl.arachne.cz/) that looks quite promising, but don't know how to use it (download vie wget, apt-get install package, and then what?).